# Mostrar fotos SD android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con el codigo que expongo acontinuacion, el codigo funciona perfectamente en level api 19 de mi celular y level api 26 desde el emulador, el inconveniente como tal es que en api level 22 y 24 que son otros celulares que he probado el codigo no funciona

```
final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
        null, orderBy);
int image_column_index = imagecursor != null ? imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID) : 0;


for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    thumbnails.add(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null));
    arrPath.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
    thumbnailsselection.add(false);
}
assert imagecursor != null;
imagecursor.close();

imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

funciona excelente level api 19 que es mi celular y 26 en el emulador, pero en otros celulares que lo he probado level api 22 y 24 no funciona

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** . ¿Tienes algún error con este código?, debes [edit] y agregar mas información en tu pregunta.

Comment: Jorge, que no funciona? Te lanza algun error? Intenta ser mas especifico.

Comment: El codigo funciona bien en ciertos celulares, pero en otros no